# Component Link resolver to second broker database

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

GraphQLLinkResolver resolves a link URI (TCM URI or site URL) to a normalized site URL. It's configured in site\unity.config.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/5c24bcc990f53a7357362b94e2526fd05a3f710b/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Resolvers/Linking/GraphQLLinkResolver.cs)

It works but the problem is that we have 2 broker databases and want to resolve it from both publications. It is possible to create a implementation class but is it possible to access also other broker database as well? How can we do this without merge the two together?

[image: 2 websites shares the content]

Comment: Can you explain why you want to resolve links across broker databases? This is not supported by CD Linking APIs either.

Comment: Company has two different website. the components (content) is common, you can refer to component from 2nd website, only then you want it to be resolved.

Comment: But two different websites doesn't imply two different broker databases, right?

Comment: Maybe webistes are separated based on architectural principles, service level agreements. 1 broker database will certainly solve this. You say there is no other option?

Comment: Cross-publication resolving only works with a single database, yes.

Comment: Technically speaking it will probably be possible to create a custom Link Resolver in DXA which works across CD instances, but I wouldn't recommend such a setup in general.